# How to update session array in laravel 4 - updated with new items

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm using ajax and laravel 4 and I upload files that are arrays - they are multiple. But I'm not sure how to update session array withe the new array. I've tried array_merge but it's overwrited.

My method looks like that:

```html
public function storeFiles() {
  $name = Input::get('name');
  $input = Input::all();
  $current_time = time();

  $trim_name = trim($name, '[]');
  $corporate_docs = array();

  foreach ($input[$trim_name] as $corporate) {
      $file_name = $current_time . '_' . $corporate->getClientOriginalName();

      $corporate->move(APPLICATIONS_DIR, $file_name);
      $corporate_docs[] = $file_name;
   
  }  
  $session = Session::get($name);
  if($session) {
    $docs = array_push($session, $corporate_docs); 
    Session::put($name, $docs); 
  } else {
    Session::put($name, $corporate_docs);
  }
}
```

How should I merge existing session array withe the newly created?

Updated: my code now is:

```html
 $trim_name = trim($name, '[]');
                $corporate_docs = array();

                foreach ($input[$trim_name] as $corporate) {
                    if ($corporate) {
                        $file_name = $current_time . '_' . $corporate->getClientOriginalName();
                
                        $corporate->move(APPLICATIONS_DIR, $file_name);
                        $corporate_docs[] = $file_name;
                        
                    }
                }
                $session = Session::get($name);
                if (Session::has($name)) {
                     $docs = array_merge($session, $corporate_docs); //dd($docs);
                     Session::forget($name);
                     Session::put($name, $docs); dd(Session::get($name));
                } else {
                    Session::put($name, $corporate_docs);
                }
```

But it is everwwriten again. When I add first image, it is stored in session and when I add another, it is merged with the first array but when I add third image, in the newly created session array - it is first image and last image. Second image is overwriten.

Comment: So the new session variable values are from $corporate_docs array, right?

Comment: Yes, and old session values I get with Session::get($name);

Comment: Yes, was just going to suggest array_merge

Comment: BTW you can see if has() method is valid for Laravel 4 by placing a die('QA') statement inside of if block

Comment: It's working but I can't understand why it works only for 2 images, when I add third image, it stores in session first image and last image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(session()->has($name)) {
    session()->forget($name);
}

session()->put($name, $corporate_docs);
```

Comment: I shunned Session::method() in past projects...don't remember why but I think it was because I was only able to get the session()->method() to work

Comment: I'll try now, I suppose in laravel 4, it should be ```Session::has()`` .

Comment: Not sure if Laravel 4 has forget() but make sure script does forget() first if it does

Comment: I updated my question, still no result. I can't understand why it is overwritten.

Comment: I found that about `array_merge` -> The keys from the first array will be preserved. If an array key exists in both arrays, then the element from the first array will be used and the matching key's element from the second array will be ignored. That's why it is overwritten.